# Error casting a RelativeLayout to a RelativeLayout derived class

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting a runtime error saying RelativeLayout cannot be cast to my class, even though my class derives from RelativeLayout.

Here is my class:

```
public class RippleBackground extends RelativeLayout{
   ....
```

This is the line in the main activity where the crash occurs:

```
 final RippleBackground rippleBackground=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.embeddedContent);
```

And here is the layout content:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/embeddedContent"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_duration="3000"
    app:rb_scale="6"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"></RelativeLayout>
```

The error is:

```
"android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to RippleBackground"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because thats not what the object is. if you want to use your class like that you need to put your class in your layout like this

```
<com.mypackage.RippleBackground
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:id="@+id/embeddedContent"
app:rb_color="#0099CC"
app:rb_radius="32dp"
app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
app:rb_duration="3000"
app:rb_scale="6"
android:layout_marginTop="71dp"></com.mypackage.RippleBackground>
```

Comment: If I make that change I get an unable to load error due to the class not being found "ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ripples.company.com.ripples.RipplesBackground". Why is that?

Comment: make sure you put the path incorrectly and didnt misspell anything